# How to find out if final part of passed path is file, directory or mask?

Tags: c++, linux

I'm trying to make some linux C++ code to copy and list files from some arbitrary path, independently of protocol ( ftp, ssh, mtp, local, smb, etc ), so i was wondering what is the best way to check if the specified path is a simple folder path ( so i list everything in there ), a path ending in a file ( so i just list that one file ), or a mask ( like /path1/path2/*.xxx ).

The first two ones are transparently handled by my code, but the third one is eluding me...

Right now, i have something like this:

```
Entry newEntry ( path );
if newEntry.IsDirectory ()
    {
    newEntry.ListContentsIntoArray(Array);
    foreach Entry in Array
        DisplayInfo ( Entry );
    }
else
    DisplayInfo ( newEntry );
```

but i have no idea how to do it if it ends in a wildcard mask...
Any ideas?

Comment: For differing between files and directories, require directories to have a trailing slash, while files does not? As for the "mask", just look for the special wildcard characters?

Comment: I agree with @JoachimPileborg, but bear in mind that it's actually legal to create a file with '*' and '?' characters in the name (on virtually all unix-derived systems). The "wildcard mask" is a shell convention.

Answer (score 0):

Posix has got an API for wildcard expansion: `glob()`:

C.f.

```
man 3p glob
```

(if you have got the posix manpages installed on your system).

Note that you can also hand plain directory and regular filenames to `glob()`.
This might simplify your code.
You can also ask `glob()` to append a `/` to each expanded entry if it is a directory (flag: `GLOB_MARK`).

Comment: well, i can determine if the full path is a file or folder easily, my main problem is with wildcards. also, bear in mind this will be run against remote paths, so i cannot use anything that would try to resolve the wildcard itself ( because its not local ), i just need to know if it is indeed a wildcard or not.